# How can I get the value of a component I created?

Tags: reactjs

I created a component (it's actually a function but I think they're called components?) for a Select Field.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    formControl: {
      minWidth: 120,
    },
    selectEmpty: {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
    },
}))

export default function SelectField() {
    const classes = useStyles()
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState("")
    return(
        <FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl}>
            <InputLabel id="age">Age</InputLabel>
            <Select
                labelId="age"
                id="age"
                label="Age"
                key="index"
                value={value}
                onChange={(val) => setValue(val)}
            >
                <MenuItem value=""><em>None</em></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
            </Select>
        </FormControl>
    )
}
```

And I'm using this Select field on another "component" (I'll only show the import for that field).

```
import SelectField from './fields/select'


export default function CreateGame(){
    const [questions, setQuestions] = React.useState([{
        question: 'asdasdasd',
        answer: '',
        score: '',
        age: ''
    }])
    const HandleField = (event, index, field) => {
        let temp_questions = questions
        temp_questions[index][field] = event.target.value
        setQuestions(temp_questions)
        console.log(questions)
    }
    const setAge = (e, index) => {
        let questions_temp = questions
        questions_temp[index]['age'] = e.target.value
        setQuestions(questions_temp)
        console.log(questions)
    }
    return(
        <Card>
            <CardContent>
                <Typography>
                    Add Questions
                </Typography>

                {questions.map((value, index) =>
                    <Grid container spacing={1}>
                        <Grid item lg={2}>
                            <TextField
                                value={value['question']}
                                key={index}
                                label='Question'
                                variant='outlined'
                                onChange={e => HandleField(e, index, 'question')} />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item lg={2}>
                            <TextField
                                value={value['answer']}
                                key={index}
                                label='Answer'
                                variant='outlined'
                                onChange={e => HandleField(e, index, 'answer')} />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item lg={2}>
                            <TextField
                                value={value['score']}
                                label='Score'
                                key={index}
                                variant='outlined'
                                onChange={HandleField} />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item lg={5}>
                            <SelectField age={value['age']} setAge={setAge} index={index} />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                )}
                

            </CardContent>
            <Button>Add</Button>
        </Card>
    )
}
```

I want to get my `<SelectField />`'s selected value and save it in my `questions` state, specifically in the `age` field. But I don't know exactly how to capture that value. I tried putting a value prop, but I don't think that's the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the state only in the parent, and pass it down as a prop, as well as another prop - a function which, when called, sets the age in the parent.

You also need to correct the shape of `onChange` - it accepts an argument of the *event*, not of the new value.

```
// in CreateGame
const setAge = i => (newAge) => {
    setQuestions([
        questions.slice(0, i),
        { ...questions[i], age: newAge },
        questions.slice(i + 1),
    ]);
};
// ...
<Grid item lg={5}>
    <SelectField age={questions.age} setAge={setAge(index)} />
</Grid>
```

```
export default function SelectField({ age, setAge }) {
    // ...
    <Select
        value={age}
        onChange={e => setAge(e.currentTarget.value)}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Although I haven't written it yet, my plan is to have multiple objects with question, answer, score and age. If you look at the `return` in `CreateGame`, I am mapping questions to create multiple fields based on how many objects `questions` has.

Comment: I suggest keeping to standard input prop naming conventions, `value`, `onChange`, `options`, etc... if you plan on keeping `Select` a generic select input.

Comment: @DrewReese If this `SelectField` is meant only for ages, as it appears from the current code, I think I'd prefer to make things explicit. `age` and `setAge` are more informative for a reader of the code than `value` and `setValue`. Is there something that recommends against this? Spreading is nice, but I wouldn't do it at the expense of code clarity

Comment: I tried implementing your solution, but I'm getting an error when I choose a value on my SelectField. The error has to do with the mapping of questions. It says it is an invalid function.

Comment: @plasmy What exactly is the `Select` component from, is it some particular library? If your original `onChange` works, I don't see any fundamental differeneces that would cause my version not to work. But it's odd for the `onChange` to appear to accept the *new value* as a parameter, rather than the *event* as with normal DOM element handlers

Comment: It is From Material UI

Comment: @plasmy See https://material-ui.com/api/select/, it's like I thought - your original function signature isn't right, the first parameter is the *event*, not the new value

Comment: So I did manage to make it work. What I'm not getting here, and this is a bit outside my question, but when I use my hook `setQuestions`, I'm seeing in console that my `questions` is being updated, but it does not reflect on the field. Do I need to do anything else outside of the `setQuestions`? I would appreciate your help. I think the problem is with the mapping. Maybe there is a different way I need to do it.

Comment: @plasmy Oh, I missed that `questions` is an array, not a single object. It sounds like the code you have currently is mutating the object, when you need to create a new state *copy* without changing any of the prior objects in state. One way to do this is to `.slice` the array of questions before and after the index that needs to be changed, and spread the updated object in between them.

Comment: I updated my original question to show what I am doing. I am very aware that `setAge` and `HandleField` are very redundant, and I plan on fixing this soon. Bu, what I want to show is that I am making a copy of questions, updating it with the value and then using `setQuestions`. This is somewhat similar to what I used to do when doing components and using `setState`. The difference is I'm not seeing the update in the fields. Also as you can see my initial state of `questions` includes a default value, and this default value is shown in the field. Thank you so much for all your help.

Comment: @plasmy Yep, you're mutating the existing state. (You should never mutate state in React.) Copy the new object into state without mutating anything in the old state instead, like in the code in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can go through these steps

```
- Step 1 Make an onchange event listener

    <SelectField onChange={handleQuestion}/>   

- Step 2 Use Hooks to make a state inside functional component
   

const [Question, setQuestion] = useState("")

- Step 3 Make the method that you had called in step 1

    const handleQuestion = () =>{
             //First get the value coming fron the onchange listener
             console.log(e.target.value);
             //Set the state to the question
             setQuestion(e.target.value)
    
        }

- Step 4 Pass the value to the question

    <TextField
             value={Question}//Pass the questions state value here
            />
```